# definition of static const outside the class definition

Tags: c++, c++11

Should we define a `static const` member outside of the class definition even if it is initialised inside the class?

```
#include<iostream>  
using namespace std;  
class abc  
{  
    static const int period=5;  
    int arr[period];  
  public:  
    void display()   
    {   
        cout<<period<<endl;  
    }  
};

const int abc::period;   

int main()   
{   
    abc a;  
    a.display();   
    return 0;  
}
```

After commenting `// const int abc::period;`, both versions of the code run fine on gcc 4.3.4. So I want to ask why do both versions work and which one is standard compliant?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are *defining* the static member`period` by writing `const int abc::period;`. You are allowed to provide an in class initializer for `static const` member of a class but that's not definition, but that's merely a declaration.

> 9.4.2/4 - If a static data member is of const integral or const enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify a constant-initializer which shall be an integral constant expression (5.19). In that case, the member can appear in integral constant expressions. The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is used in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not contain an initializer.

Your code compiles even without the definition because you are not taking the address of the static member. Bjarne Stroustrup mentions in the C++-FAQ [here](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#in-class) that *You can take the address of a static member if (and only if) it has an out-of-class definition*

Comment: In this question (which is surely a duplicate) I think it is interesting to explain what **used** means in the context of §9.4.2/4, as it is not intuitive, and why the definition is not needed otherwise. The first part is somehow stated in *because you are not taking the address*, but I am not sure most people will realize that that is an approximation of the term *used*.

Comment: @David : I tried to search for the word **use** in the Standard. Unfortunately couldn't find the relevant text at the time of this post.

Comment: :) I tried also some time ago, and didn't find any single clear definition in C++03 that I can post, but *use as an lvalue where an lvalue to rvalue conversion is no immediately performed* is a slightly better approximation. For a case where this definition applies and *taking the address* doesn't: `(cond?static_const:XXX)`, with `cond` being a condition, `static_const` being a, well, static constant in a class. If `XXX` is an rvalue it does not constitute use. `static_const` is an rvalue but immediately converted to lvalue. If `XXX` is an lvalue, then that constitutes *use*. No address taken.

Comment: Example: `struct test { static const int s = 1; }; int main( int argc, char** ) { const int y = ( argc < test::s? argc : test::s); }` The first use of `test::s` does not constitute *use*: `argc < test::s`, the constant is an lvalue, but a immediate conversion to rvalue (it's value), is performed. On the other hand, the `...: test::s )` does constitute *use*. The ternary expression can be understood as (pseudo code): `const int* __p; if ( argc<test::s ) __p = &argc; else __p = &test::s; *__p;`.

Comment: If the expression is changed to `( argc < test::s? argc : test+0 )`, then in both subexpressions, there is an immediate conversion to rvalue, and they don't constitute use. The equivalent pseudo code would be: `int __i; if ( argc < test::s ) __i = argc; else __i = test+0; __i;`

Comment: @David : Nicely summarized! :-)

Comment: **damn!** three comments above the last sentence should read: *static_const is an **lvalue** but immediately converted to an **rvalue***

Comment: @David : Never mind. Understood from the context that it was indeed a typo. :-)