# Weird linker problem with static const class members

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, linker, static-members

Please tell me, why **gcc** linker gives me the following error: **"test_class::test_struct::constVar", referenced from: __ZN12lu_test_class27test_struct6constVar$non_lazy_ptr in test_class.o** ?

My code (**test_class.h**):

```
class test_class
{
    struct test_struct
    {
         static const int constVar = 0;
    };
};
```

All references to **constVar** are in **test_class** scope in a usual static member access form: **test_struct::constVar**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide the definition of the static member outside the class

```
const int test_class::test_struct::constVar;
```

[This](http://www.ideone.com/fzcmL) works for me.

Comment: Thanks, Prasoon! Can anybody please explain why is it necessary?

Comment: @Ryan : Yes! Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106194/definition-of-static-const-outside-the-class-definition/6106240#6106240) answer. :)

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but the problem is not solved - I get linker error 'duplicate symbol test_class::test_struct::constVar' even though the header file with constVar definition is included only once and I use the --allow-multiple-definition (just in case)... Please help!

Comment: Nevermind, actually... I think the root of this problem is that constVar is not a public member in my case. I wonder why gcc thinks everything is fine though...

Comment: I ended up relocating static const members outside of class scope in order to avoid GCC 4.2.1 linker problems...