# C++ static const class members initialization

Tags: c++

I'd like to have a class that has *static* members to itself, but I can't figure how to do that. Is that even possible?

I get the error:

> only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class

Code:

```
namespace misc
{
    class CData
    {
    public:
        CData( ) { };
        CData( int d );

        CData& operator = ( const CData& d );

        static const CData FIRST = CData( 512 ); //how?

    private:
        int data;
    };
}
```

As I use `FIRST` a lot I would like to statically access it using `misc::CData::FIRST` without the need to declare it somewhere in the scope. Is that by any chance possible?

Comment: You're using an old compiler, or it's in legacy mode.  Try adding `--std=c++11` (or `--std=gnu++11`) to your compiler options.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106194/definition-of-static-const-outside-the-class-definition

Comment: Why is your title "static const integral members"? That is quite misleading.

Comment: You would like for `FIRST` to be a static data member because you access it a lot? And why the restriction against declaring (I'm assuming you meant *defining*) it elsewhere?

Comment: @juanchopanza: Because that's the error message given by his pre-C++11 compiler.

Comment: @BenVoigt That is part of the error message. It does not form a suitable question title though.

Comment: Lets say you have declared `FIRST` as a member of `CData`, then *defining* the member outside of the scope of the class does *not* mean that you redeclare it in global scope. It's still a member of `CData`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... without the need to declare it somewhere in the scope. Is that by any chance possible?

No, it's not possible without declaring it (which you already tried to do in your class declaration). You probably meant, without *defining* it outside your class declaration. Again the answer is no.
You have to separate declaration and definition for this case (it only works with primitive integral types like `int` to initialize these directly in the class declaration).

First have a simple declaration in your class declaration (usually something like `CData.hpp`)

```
namespace misc {
    class CData {
    public:
        CData( ) { };
        CData( int d );

        CData& operator = ( const CData& d );

        static const CData& FIRST;

    private:
        int data;
    };
}
```

and then define it in a separate compilation unit (usually something like `CData.cpp`)

```
namespace misc {
    const CData& CData::FIRST = CData( 512 );
}
```

Comment: "...without the need to decleare it somewhere in the scope..."

Comment: @privatedatapublicchannel2 _"...without the need to decleare it somewhere in the scope..."_ That's as irrelevant as asking for fairies or unicorns ...

Comment: irrelevant are assumptions, but "without the need to decleare it somewhere in the scope" is a wish of the OP, it is part of the question

Comment: @privatedatapublicchannel2 Then the OP should clarify this point, don't you think so? There's often people _wish_ to have this or that from c++, that the language simply doesn't support.

Comment: I meant "global scope". I find it nicer having it inside the class "Data::FIRST" so you know what it belongs to rather than "extern DATA bla.." which is in my opinion kinda messy if you have a lot of data. Thanks for the post, this works perfect +1

Comment: @user1579704 _'rather than "extern DATA bla.."'_ Well, fortunately that's not necessary using [tag:c++], in contrast to plain [tag:c] global instances :-) ...

Comment: This was helpful.  The only problem is gcc won't compile `static const& CData FIRST;`.  However, `static const CData& FIRST;` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

> ... without the need to declare it somewhere in the scope. Is that by
>   any chance possible?

No.

C++ Standard n3337 **§** 9.4.2/2

Static data members

> The declaration of a static data member in its class definition is not
>   a definition and may be of an incomplete type other than cv-qualified
>   void. The definition for a static data member shall appear in a
>   namespace scope enclosing the member’s class definition. (...)

You can declare a static data member in class:

```
namespace misc {
    class CData {
    public:
        //...
        static const CData FIRST;  // declaration
        //...
}
```

and define it in (exactly) one of the .cpp files:

```
namespace misc {
    CData CData::FIRST = CData( 512 );  // definition
}
```

This is preferred solution, however you need to have this definition out of your class. You could have defined the member in class if it was of an integral type

C++ Standard n3337 **§** 9.4.2/3 says

> If a non-volatile const static data member is of integral or
>   enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify
>   a brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause that is
>   an assignment- expression is a constant expression (...)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't think the question is really related to the singleton pattern here :-/ ...

Comment: So the most straightforward way to solve the OP's problem is to create a singleton?

Comment: @Praetorian "...without the need to decleare it somewhere in the scope..."

Comment: @private data publ the example share resemblance to singleton, but it's certainly not a singleton.

Comment: Well, the OP also seems to think he needs the static data member because *he accesses it a lot*. The answer to the original problem is to provide a definition for the static member, not create a singleton. Anyway, didn't downvote, so can't help you with that.

Comment: -1 _"If you have a hammer, every actual problem looks like a nail!"_

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ can you be more precise, I would like to improve my answer

Comment: @privatedatapublicchannel2 _'can you be more precise'_ Of course I can [LMGTFY](https://www.google.de/webhp?source=search_app&gfe_rd=cr&ei=C6Z7U9-bIo_Jsgb024H4Bg#q=If+you+have+a+hammer%2C+every+actual+problem+looks+like+a+nail!) Singleton obviously doesn't apply for the OP's case.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I mean, can you please cite the part of my answer that is a cause of your downvote so I can improve this?

Comment: @privatedatapublicchannel2 If any of the GoF patterns are in question there it's more about the [**Flyweight**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) IMHO. Having certain `static const T` instances along with a certain class to give useful _common_ values like e.g. `ZERO`, `PI`or `NORMAL_MATRIX`, whatever, is a commonly used and valid technique. I hope you get my point now.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ changed, please consider

Comment: @privatedatapublicchannel2 Yes, and now it's correct (cleared the downvote), but doesn't provide any additional information to the accepted answer :-/ ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ now it does provide additional info

Comment: @privatedatapublicchannel2 [**you've come a long way baby**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFSIxxhGKoA&list=PL6945C3CDF92F3AE4)

Answer (score 0):

For non-integral data, something like this is preferred since it avoids the [static initialization fiasco.](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html)

```
static const CData FIRST()
{
    static CData first(512); //only initialized once, when first requested

    return first;
}
```