# makefile.win error while compiling c++ on dev c++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Im trying to run my code with my own self defined header file in dev c++ .

but when I compile it  get this error :

```
25      C:\Users\ali\Desktop\hw2\Makefile.win   recipe for target 'tar.exe' failed
```

and it points to this line in makefile.win:

```
    $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)
```

And also I have added my files to my project :
main.cpp&post.cpp&post.h

here are my codes(only PostBox class):

in header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#ifndef P
#define P
class PostBox{
friend void Send(PostBox);
public:
    int getcount();
    void Count();
    PostBox(string,float,int,Person,Person);
    PostBox();
    void setID(string);
    void setweight(float);
    void setsender(Person);
    void setreceiver(Person);
    void cost();
    string getid();
    Person getsender();
    Person getreceiver();
protected:
    static int count;
    string id;
    float weight;
    int price;
    Person sender;
    Person receiver;
};
 #endif
```

in my cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "post.h"
using namespace std;
PostBox::PostBox(string id,float weight,int price,Person sender,Person      receiver)
{
this->count=0;
this->id=id;
this->weight=weight;
this->price=price;
this->sender=sender;
this->receiver=receiver;
}
```

Comment: Aren't there any other error messages from the linker?

Comment: C:\Users\ali\Desktop\hw2\post.o post.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZN7PostBox5countE[.refptr._ZN7PostBox5countE]+0x0): undefined reference to `PostBox::count'

Comment: So it's not a problem with your makefile. Did you check, that you have implemented a definition for `PostBox::count`? I'd guess you are missing a definition for a static class variable.

Comment: count is a statig variable...its not a  function

Comment: Yes I said this, you need to define static class variables you have declared in your header. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767241/c-static-const-class-members-initialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing your declaration of the `static int ::count`.

Put something like this into your cpp file `int PostBox::count = 0`.